# Are [[locked]-questions] [locked]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

We have both [locked](/questions/tagged/locked) and [locked-questions](/questions/tagged/locked-questions), but not [locked-answers](/questions/tagged/locked-answers).

Judging by the posts tagged by them, it appears to me they're good candidates for a merge.

Also, the excerpt of [locked](/questions/tagged/locked) reads

> For questions **regarding locked posts** and ....

Comment: The tags can be merged into locked-posts, but the tag needs to exist first.